# DNN DDRMenu: xslt template to display rootlevel

Tags: xml, xslt, dotnetnuke, breadcrumbs, ddrmenu

I'm developing a breadcrumb for DotNetNuke 7 using the DDRMenu XSLT Templates.

The codes I am using are working fine however I want to display the rootlevel of the breadcrumbs without hardcoding it.

What I have in my breadcrumbs now is:

```
    News & Publications / Speeches / Test123
```

News&Publications is a subpage of my menu and what I'm trying to achieve is to show the rootlevel

```
    Home / News & Publications / Speeches / Test123
```

Here is my XSLT Template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:param name="CSSClass">breadcrumb</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="separator"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="root">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//node[@breadcrumb =1]" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node">
        <li>
            <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="$separator" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@enabled = 1 and @selected !=1">
                    <a href="{@url}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
                    </a>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the input XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<manifest>
    <template>Breadcrumb.xslt</template>
    <stylesheets>
        <stylesheet>[MANIFEST]/breadcrumb.css</stylesheet>
    </stylesheets>
    <defaultTemplateArguments>
        <templateArgument name="CSSClass" value="breadcrumb" />
    </defaultTemplateArguments>
</manifest>
```

Below is the Example XML the menu component uses

```
<Root>
    <root>
        <node id="37" text="Home" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Home.T37.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="1" last="0" only="0" depth="0" >
            <description >Upgrade your standard DNN menu - automatically and for free - to an SEO-optimised, accessible, mobile-friendly, cross-browser menu.</description>
        </node>

        <node id="56" text="DNN Menu" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/DNN-Menu.T56.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="1" first="0" last="0" only="0" depth="0" >
            <node id="97" text="Menu features" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Menu-features.T97.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="1" last="0" only="0" depth="1" />
            <node id="111" text="Pre-built templates" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Pre-built-templates.T111.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="0" last="0" only="0" depth="1" >
                <node id="94" text="Standard DNN menu, upgraded" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Standard-DNN-menu-upgraded.T94.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="1" last="0" only="0" depth="2" />
                <node id="124" text="Superfish template" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Superfish-template.T124.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="0" last="0" only="0" depth="2" />
                <node id="106" text="Treeview template" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Treeview-template.T106.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="0" last="0" only="0" depth="2" />
                <node id="107" text="Accordion template" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Accordion-template.T107.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="0" last="0" only="0" depth="2" />
                <node id="112" text="Dropdown template" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Dropdown-template.T112.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="0" last="0" only="0" depth="2" />
                <node id="96" text="Mega-menu" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Mega-menu.T96.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="0" last="1" only="0" depth="2" />
            </node>
            <node id="113" text="Getting started" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Getting-started.T113.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="0" last="0" only="0" depth="1" >
                <node id="114" text="Installing the menu" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Installing-the-menu.T114.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="1" last="0" only="0" depth="2" />
                <node id="115" text="Upgrading a SolPart menu" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Upgrading-a-SolPart-menu.T115.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="0" last="0" only="0" depth="2" />
                <node id="116" text="Upgrading a DNNMenu" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Upgrading-a-DNNMenu.T116.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="0" last="0" only="0" depth="2" />
                <node id="117" text="Installing a template" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Installing-a-template.T117.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="0" last="0" only="0" depth="2" />
                <node id="118" text="Adding to a skin" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Adding-to-a-skin.T118.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="0" last="1" only="0" depth="2" />
            </node>
            <node id="119" text="Customising templates" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Customising-templates.T119.aspx"   enabled="0" selected="0" breadcrumb="1" first="0" last="1" only="0" depth="1" >
                <node id="120" text="Standard options" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Standard-options.T120.aspx"         enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="1" last="0" only="0" depth="2" />
                <node id="121" text="Specifying filenames" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Specifying-filenames.T121.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="0" last="0" only="0" depth="2" />
                <node id="122" text="XML format" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/XML-format.T122.aspx"                     enabled="1" selected="1" breadcrumb="1" first="0" last="0" only="0" depth="2" />
                <node id="123" text="Creating custom templates" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Creating-custom-templates.T123.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="0" last="1" only="0" depth="2" />
            </node>
        </node>

        <node id="87" text="Download" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Download.T87.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="0" last="0" only="0" depth="0" />

        <node id="85" text="Contact" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Contact.T85.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="0" last="1" only="0" depth="0" >
            <node id="129" text="Blog" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Blog.T129.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="1" last="0" only="0" depth="1" />
            <node id="130" text="Forum" url="http://www.dnndoneright.com/Forum.T130.aspx" enabled="1" selected="0" breadcrumb="0" first="0" last="1" only="0" depth="1" />
        </node>
    </root>
</Root>
```

Comment: can you post also your input XML?

Comment: Hi Joel, I've edited my post to include the XML.

Comment: I don't see any `root` and `node` there.

Comment: I think DNN and DDRmenu handles the components in the program thus I don't have to create a seperate XML to operate it. I have been using the sample template provided by DNN and I just made changes in the XSLT.

Comment: Included the example XML of the menu component in case you need it for reference. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this to get the breadcrumbs

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="//node[@breadcrumb =1]" />
```

Try doing this to get the firs node under **root** too

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="node[@first=1]|//node[@breadcrumb =1]" />
```

Note the union operator `|` will only get distinct elements so that if the "root" node is also marked as a breadcrumb, it won't get selected (and output) twice.

Comment: Hi Tim, however the first page on my menu is not home but a page on getting started. I'm currently displaying it by using this method:
   <xsl:apply-templates select="//node[@breadcrumb =1 or @title='Home']" />
however if there is another way to check if it is the home page, I would prefer that method just in case in future the home page name is changed.

Comment: Well, it should select the very first "node" under the "root", which in your example XML is the root. If this is not the case, then you will need to determine some other way to uniquely identify what the "Home" node is.